# Solving $\{n^2 + n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \{2n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have been solving this problem from Velleman's `How to prove` book:

$\{n^2 + n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \{2n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

This is my solution so far:

$\forall x (x \in \left\{n^2 + n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}) \implies (x \in \left\{2n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \right\})$
$\forall x (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x = n^2 + n + 1)) \implies (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x=2n+1)) $

But the answer given in the book is:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\exists m \in \mathbb{N}(n^2 + n + 1 = 2m + 1)$

I'm not able to understand how that answer is correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may add some condiderations :

*(i)* from an "intuitive" point of view, it is easy to convince inself that the number $n^2 + n +1$, for all $n$ is *odd*; thus, it must be obviously true that :

> $\{ n^2+n+1 | n \in \mathbb N \} \subseteq \{ 2m+1 | m \in \mathbb N \}$.

*(ii)* the defining condition for set *inclusion* is :

> $A \subseteq B$ **iff** for all $x$, if $x \in A$, then $x \in A$;

in our example, this is :

> forl all $x$, if $\exists n (x = n^2+n+1)$, then $\exists m (x = 2m+1)$.

*Note* : having rewritten the defining condition in explicit form (i.e. without the set-builder "operator" $\{ n | \varphi(n) \}$), we can verify that the variables $n,m$ are *bound*. Thus, it does not matter what variable we use, and using the same variable in both formulae can be misleading, because there is no "link" between the two.

*(iii)* now we can "formalize" the above facts with a single first-order formula expressing the condition for inclusion :

> $\forall x(\exists n (x = n^2+n+1) \rightarrow \exists m (x = 2m+1))$ --- **(*)**.

We can use some logical laws to transform the last formula.

We have that :

> if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$, then $(∃x \beta → \alpha) ↔ ∀x(\beta → \alpha)$.

Thus, applying it to **(*)** [$n$ is not free in $\exists m (x = 2m+1)$], we get the equivalent formula :

> $\forall x \forall n ((x = n^2+n+1) \rightarrow \exists m (x = 2m+1))$.

Now we use :

> if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$, then $(\alpha → ∃x \beta) ↔ ∃x(\alpha → \beta)$.

Applying it to the above formula [$m$ is not free in $(x = n^2+n+1)$] we have :

> $\forall x \forall n \exists m ((x = n^2+n+1) \rightarrow (x = 2m+1))$

which is again equivalent to **(*)**.

The last transformation is licensed by *identity* laws :

> if $x = a$ and $x = b$, then $a = b$.

Applying it to : $(x = n^2+n+1) \rightarrow ((x = 2m+1) \rightarrow (n^2+n+1 = 2m+1))$ we can get the final transformation of **(*)** :

> > > $\forall n \exists m (n^2+n+1 = 2m+1)$.

Comment: What does it mean by `If x does not occur free in α` ?

Comment: @Sibi - $\alpha$ is a formula whatever, If $\alpha$ is e.g. $\exists y (y=x+1)$ we have that $x$ has a free occurrence in it (we say : $x$ is *free* in $\alpha$) while $y$ has **no** free occurrences in it (we say : $y$ is *bound* in $\alpha$). $y$ is "bounded" by the leading quantifier $\exists y$.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any name for this law `if x does not occur free in α, then (∃xβ→α)↔∀x(β→α).` ? I don't think I have seen that yet in the book.

Comment: @Sibi - is one of the laws for "prenexing" the quantifiers; see [Prenex form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $n^2 + n + 1 = n(n+1) + 1$, and $2|n(n+1)$

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $\{n^2 + n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \{2n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, pick any $x \in \{n^2 + n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \} $, we are wanted to prove that $x \in \{2n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Suppose that $x=k^2+k+1$. Then $x=k(k+1)+1$. Clearly $2|k(k+1)$, hence exists $n \Bbb N$ such that $k(k+1)=2n$, and hence $x=2n+1$.

Comment: Thanks, but how does that say that it is finally equivalent to $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\exists m \in \mathbb{N}(n^2 + n + 1 = 2m + 1)$ ?

Comment: @sibi In the last line, change the $k$ to an $n$ and the $n$ to an m and instead of $x$ in the last line $n^2+n+1$.

Comment: Thanks, what is the symbol `|` mean in `2|k(k+1)`. I haven't seen them being used outside of a set notation ?

Answer (score 0):

Note the $n$ in two sets are independent. If you are confused, you may write the second set as $\{2m + 1 | m \in \mathbb{N} \}$, which refers the exactly same set as $\{2n + 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

To show $A\subset B$, you need to show $\forall x\in A$, $x\in B$. That is, if $x$ satisfies the requirement of set $A$, then it must satisfy the requirement of being in set $B$. In your case, it's just what the solution means. Hence what you need to do is to show $2|n^2 + n$, which can be done by discussing the cases where $n$ is odd or even.